# ReaderWriterLock never throws ApplicationException

Tags: c#

Even after timeout interval has expired in AcquireReaderLock(timeout) or AcquireWritterLock(timeout), ApplicationException isn't thrown. Anyone know why?

```
        try
        {
            _readWritterLock.AcquireReaderLock(3000);
            IEnumerable<TEntity> result;
            try
            {
                result = _xmlReader.GetAll();
            }
            catch
            {

                result = new List<TEntity>();
            }
            finally
            {
                _readWritterLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App Exception");
            return new List<TEntity>();
        }
```

Comment: Why it should throw an `ApplicationException`?

Comment: Silly question, but are you 100% certain it's timed-out?

Comment: Please post a minimal but *complete* program that reproduces the problem. The code you posted is minimal, but is not *complete*, so we can't use it to run it ourselves and see what happens. In fact, as pointed out already, based on the code that we can see, why should we assume that the call timed out? Also, consider switching to [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx), which is preferred over `ReaderWriterLock`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual studio 2015, then you can Enable it in the Exception settings found at **Debug-> Windows -> Exception Settings** (or **Ctrl+ALt+E** by default). Then go to **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** and you will find it there.
in **Visual Studio 2013** you will find it in **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**->**System**. not sure about the other products

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what a minimal but complete program looks like:

```
public static void Main()
{
   var rwl = new ReaderWriterLock();
   rwl.AcquireWriterLock(1000);

   var t1 = new Thread(() =>
   {
      try
      {
         rwl.AcquireReaderLock(1000);
         Console.WriteLine("Acquired lock successfully");
      }
      catch (ApplicationException)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Time out");
      }
   });

   t1.Start();
   t1.Join();

   rwl.ReleaseWriterLock();
}
```

If you copy-paste the code and run it, you will see that the output is:

> Time out

... as expected.  So the `ReaderWriterLock` class does throw an `ApplicationException` as expected.

See if you can do the same. Create a little main that strips down what you are doing to the bare essentials until you can narrow down the problem.  And if you're still struggling, post the *minimal but complete* code here so that we can copy paste it and just run it.

Regardless of what your problem may be, you should really look into using the more recent [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead.  Notice what it says under the **Remarks** section for the [ReaderWriterLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

> The .NET Framework has two reader-writer locks, `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and `ReaderWriterLoc`. `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is recommended for all new development. `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is similar to `ReaderWriterLock`, but it has simplified rules for recursion and for upgrading and downgrading lock state. `ReaderWriterLockSlim` avoids many cases of potential deadlock. In addition, the performance of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is significantly better than `ReaderWriterLock`.